# Get correct NTFS filenames with unicode characters in Linux

Tags: python, linux, string, encoding, ntfs

I have an NTFS partition mounted in Linux. Due to the encoding difference, all Unicode characters in filenames are broken. E.g. `新建文件夹` (New folder in Chinese) is shown as `\320½\250\316ļ\376\274\320/`.

I cannot change the mount option thus I want to write a Python script to get the correct filename.
Here is what I tried (still using the `新建文件夹` example):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir('.')[-1]
'\udcd0½\udca8\udcceļ\udcfe\udcbc\udcd0'
>>> os.listdir(b'.')[-1]
b'\xd0\xc2\xbd\xa8\xce\xc4\xbc\xfe\xbc\xd0'
>>> os.listdir(b'.')[-1].decode('utf-16')
'싐ꢽ쓎ﺼ킼'
```

The output is still broken text. I also tried `utf_16_be` and `utf_16_le` but they don't work. What should be the correct way to get correct NTFS filenames with unicode characters in Linux? Any comments or feedback are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `b'\xd0\xc2\xbd\xa8\xce\xc4\xbc\xfe\xbc\xd0'.decode('iso-ir-58')` produces something that looks ok to my untrained eye. Found by trying out various encodings mentioned in and around https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_encoding

Comment: @teapot418 Thank you! `iso-ir-58` is the correct encoding!